# Extract text from two lines

Tags: linux, perl, sed

Here a file which I have

```
Generate random sequence...
Appended bytes 000A - Offset
is 0x30 (collision is not found). OK.

Generate random sequence...
Appended bytes 3725 - Offset
is 0x35 (collision is found). OK.

...
```

and etc. I need extract text started since `Offset` till first dot on the next string. What I should to say `sed` (or `perl`) that it extract required text block?

Comment: Please, show the expected output.

Comment: You mean `Offset
is 0x30 (collision is not found).` You have tried anything in `sed, perl`...

Comment: `while($str=~m/Offset([^\.]+)\./gs) {  print "Matched: $&\n"; }`

Comment: @ssr1012, yes, that is.

Comment: There are various ways. (1) Process line-by line, set a flag when you find `Offset`, then look for `.`. Once you find it unset the flag , continue (2) Read by paragraphs and do a multiline regex search on each (3) Read a whole file in and do a multiline regex with `/g` ... have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -nr "/Offset/ {N; s/.*Offset\n([^\.]*\.).*/Offset \1/p}" file
```

`N` adds next line to pattern space, then do normal substitution.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I need. Should be captured all `Offset ... found).`, not only first match.

Comment: @KatePage this captures all `Offset ... found).`, not only the first!

Comment: I found where was an error! Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

In GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '{print gensub(/.*(Offset[^.]*\.).*/,"\\1",1)}' file
Offset
is 0x30 (collision is not found).
Offset
is 0x35 (collision is found).
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '                                # separare records by empty lines
{
    print gensub(/.*(Offset[^.]*\.).*/,"\\1",1) # replace record with what starts
}' file                                         # with Offset up to the first .
```

Comment: It shouldn't to capture `OK.`

Comment: U p d a t e d .

Answer (score 1):

In perl you can try this way:

```
my $str = "Generate random sequence...
Appended bytes 000A - Offset
is 0x30 (collision is not found). OK.

Generate random sequence...
Appended bytes 3725 - Offset
is 0x35 (collision is found). OK.
";

while($str=~m/Offset([^\.]+)\./gs) #Upto the first dot we will fetch the text
{ 
    print "Matched: $&\n"; #Matched string will be printed here
}
```

Comment: Shortly ```perl -0777 -nlE 'say "$&\n" while m/Offset([^\.]*)\./g' file```